# Add text to custom shape without Kinetic.Group

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am in the process of updating to kineticjs 4.7.0. I am struggling with adding text to a custom shape. 
Here the code:

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function(context) {
          this.setFill('#00D2FF');
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(200, 50);
          context.lineTo(420, 80);
          context.quadraticCurveTo(300, 100, 260, 170);
          context.closePath();
          context.fillStrokeShape(this);

          this.setFill('#FFFFFF');
          context.beginPath();
          context.fillText('Hello World!', 200, 150);
          context.closePath();
          context.fillStrokeShape(this);


        },
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });
```

How do I make the text a different color to the filling of the shape, so I don't need to use Kinetic.Shape and Kinetic.Text in a group?

Here the is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qQU6G/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears that KineticJS 4.7 has a more complete wrapper of canvas.context, but the fillText method does not yet respect either context.fillStyle or this.setFill.

**[ Update ]**

Since Kinetic's "context" is not full-featured in regards to fillText, here's a way to get the underlying context and use that to fillText with your different color.

Here's a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/df6Uv/

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(context) {
      this.setFill('#00D2FF');
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(200, 50);
      context.lineTo(420, 80);
      context.quadraticCurveTo(300, 100, 260, 170);
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStrokeShape(this);

      var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.font="18px verdana";
      ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
      ctx.fillText("Hello World!",225,90);
      ctx.restore();

    },
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I played around with your suggestions but am not able to get it working. Please have a look here [http://jsfiddle.net/qQU6G/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/qQU6G/2/). I can't get black text on top of the shape.

Comment: Ok, after experimenting for a while (including a look at Kinetic's source code), I conclude my original code theory won't work using Kinetic's current contxt wrapper (argh!).  So if you absolutely don't want to use a group to combine your shapes and other-colored-text, you will have to "cheat".  The cheat involves getting the actual CanvasRenderingContext2D and using that "real" context to style your text a new color.  See my revised answer...but realize it's truly a "cheat" and might stop working in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that drawFunc can be invoked more than once and not always you will get context from canvas you expect. Kinetic will use helper canvases sometimes. I run into problems using above approach, but wrapping "extra" code with simple check helped:

```
...
if(context.canvas._canvas.parentNode!=null){   
    var ctx=this.getContext()._context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font="18px verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World!",225,90);
    ctx.restore();
}
...
```